# manage and secure parameters added to the url by a third party

Tags: php

let's assume we have this url : mywebsite.com/product.php?id=201

in order to secure GET operations, I check the id (it must be numeric) and I check that there is only one parameter in the url and I prohibit the addition of parameters like this :

```
$whitelist = array('id');
if (test_fields($whitelist,$_GET)) {

}

 function test_fields($wl, $dt) {
    $result = True;
    foreach ($dt as $key=>$item) {
        if (!in_array($key, $wl)) {
            $result = False;
        }
        else {$result = True;}
    }
    return $result;
 }
```

the problem is that when we share this link on facebook for example, parameters are added by default like this mywebsite.com/product.php?id=201&fbclid=DIwAR0kna40q

this generates an error since I have prohibited the addition of parameters

do you have any idea how to get around this?

besides that, I have another problem
to manage the SEO aspect I retrieve the uri using ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) of the page and I retrieve the seo elements (title, description, h1, index, etc.) from a database based on the uri
but since the uri changes when facebook adds a parameter, I no longer find this uri in my database

do you have an idea to solve that or if not, an idea to better manage the seo aspect of this kind of pages?

thank you

Comment: _"I check that there is only one parameter in the url and I prohibit the addition of parameters"_ - Why? Only fetch the parameters you need and ignore the rest. Regarding `REQUEST_URI`, you should only match on the path (the part before the `?`), so remove the query string from it before matching. In the DB, only store the path as well.

Comment: you mean there is no risk if there are additional "strange" parameters and I don't have to check them? if so that solves my first problem... thanks (ok i'll try your solution for the 2nd problem ;)

Comment: Query params don't do or affect anything unless you fetch them and use them for something. If you just ignore them, they won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple is the method.

If you got Get Parameters like:

`URI?id=1&id2=2&id3=3` and you need only **id** just get only this one,it doesn't matter if there are 10 more.

**1. STANDARD**

```
<?php
 $GET_ID =  ($_GET['id']);
?>
```

**2. IF NOT EXISTS SET SOMETHING**

```
<?php
 $GET_ID =  ($_GET['id'] ?? 'SETSOMETHING');
?>
```

**3. IF NOT EXISTS SET SOMETHING, AND YOU CAN SET A LIMIT OF THE STRING LENGHT**

```
<?php
 $GET_ID =  substr(($_GET['id'] ?? 'SETSOMETHING'), 0, 30);
?>
```

**4. IF NOT EXISTS SET SOMETHING, USE A FUNCTION TO DO SOMETHING AND YOU CAN SET A LIMIT OF THE STRING LENGHT**

```
<?php
 $GET_ID =  substr(MYFUNCTION($_GET['id'] ?? 'SETSOMETHING'), 0, 50);
?>
```

And for your URI use php **parse_url** from (php.net)
[parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php)

Just select what you need.

```
<?php

$url = 'http://username:password@hostname:9090/path?arg=value#anchor';

var_dump(parse_url($url));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_USER));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PASS));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PORT));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT));
?>
```

Comment: _Side note:_ Just do: `$foo = $bar;`, no need for parentheses like `$foo = ($bar);`

Comment: It's my coding style, like in the bash $foo or ${foo}. In math you can put as many brackets as you want if the logic is right.

Comment: Sure, but imho, it does actually make it a bit harder to read when you add extra unnecessary fluff. Btw, it's also `$_GET`, not `$GET_`

Comment: Yes, Thank you. Prescribed and than copy|paste ^^